# Is a #4 nylon washer the right size for a 4-40 nut?

Tags: mechanical-engineering

I need nylon washers to sit between a 4-40 nut and a circuit board to insulate the nut. I'm assuming a #4 washer would be similar in size to the nut.

Answer (score 3):

The term "4-40" indicates a #4 size nut with 40 threads per inch. So yes, a #4 washer is correct.